# Espresso test is not finishing and it keeps on finding element when there is an issue in the application

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, ui-testing, android-espresso-recorder

I have the espresso test. When there is any issue in the app the test is not finishing and it keeps on staying on the same screen. Is there anyway we can give timeout for the espresso test. I cant find solution for the global timeout. Junit Android Espresso Test

```
@Before
public static void beforeClass() {
    IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: This usually happens when your UI thread is never idle. Disable any animations and make sure you don't have videos playing

Comment: Nehemias G Miranda : no animations available but still it takes time. Let me add timeouts if it works will mark your answer

Answer (score 2):

You could add a timeout rule.
E.g. Rule to timeout after 2 minutes

```
@get:Rule val globalTimeout: Timeout = Timeout.seconds(120)
```

Comment: I tried this and its not working